# PhpStorm red lines in the code

Tags: phpstorm

Suddenly PhpStorm looks like that:

[image: red lined codes]

I deleted and re-installed it. However that didn't change anything.

Comment: I do not know .. but at first glance looks like some Code Coverage info. Does it work OK in another project? In worse case -- you can delete the IDE-wide settings (to start from scratch -- link below) and/or this project settings (`.idea` subfolder). https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: It's normal for other projects. I'll check to the link thank you

Comment: Show screenshot of the whole IDE. No need to delete IDE-wide settings right now if it works in other projects.

Comment: I deleted **.idea** file in project path(linux environment), It fixed, thx @LazyOne

Comment: I've downloaded the plugin 'PHPUnit code coverage' which was causing exact the above mentioned issues. Disabling it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`Alt`</kbd><kbd>`S`</kbd> to open the Settings window. Expand the `Editor` tree in the left panel. Expand `Color Scheme`, then click in `General`. In the right panel, click in `Line coverage` and uncheck `Background` checkbox on the right side.

[image]

You can also type a shortcut <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd><kbd>`Shift`</kbd><kbd>`A`</kbd> to open the actions window and type `line coverage`.